# MongoDb select many with a join on the result

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, aggregate

I am trying to perform a join on a collection from the results of a select many using the MongoDb Linq driver

pseudo code is

```
from x in something
from y in x.subcollection
join a in detailed on y.id equals a.id
select new 
{
   x.field,
   x.someotherfield,
   a.somedetail,
   a.someotherdetail
}
```

unfortunately this syntax gives me

```
System.NotSupportedException : $project or $group does not support {document}.
```

I would be open to doing this via the aggregate pipeline fluent library as well, if its not possible using the linq provider, but I have no idea of the syntax, the documentation is ... lacking ...

I assume it would be an unwind, a lookup and a projection - but how?

-------Edit-------

Getting closer, but still no cigar...

[image]

So the unwind seems to work fine, the lookup also works fine, the issue is trying to work with the resulting BsonDocument in the projection stage

I know that there are some typed overloads where I could supply a type - but it will be impractical to create intermediate types for every stage of every pipeline.

My issues are.

- I seem to have to hard cast the BsonValue's rather than use the
  AsSomething methods, which seems weird (bug?)
- The joined collection is
  included as an Array (as expected) in my case it will always have 1
  record, I can get the First ok as a BSonDocument, but I cannot drill
  further into it (the ["FirstName"] call fails with "No matching
  creator found"

Please help !

Comment: I looked here: https://www.axonize.com/blog/joining-collections-mongodb-using-c-driver-linq/